# Simplexml Insert into sub element

Tags: simplexml

i have an xml file same bellow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <prod id="1">
       <layer id="layer_0" imgSRC="data/361_layer_0.png"/>
       <layer id="layer_1" imgSRC="data/362_layer_0.png"/>
       <layer id="layer_2" imgSRC="data/363_layer_0.png"/>
     </prod>
     <prod id="2">
       <layer id="layer_0" imgSRC="data/361_layer_0.png"/>
       <layer id="layer_1" imgSRC="data/362_layer_0.png"/>
       <layer id="layer_2" imgSRC="data/363_layer_0.png"/>
     </prod>
</data>
```

how to use simplexml to insert an item into layer id="layer_3" like bellow example:

```
 <prod id="1">
   <layer id="layer_0" imgSRC="data/361_layer_0.png"/>
   <layer id="layer_1" imgSRC="data/362_layer_0.png"/>
   <layer id="layer_2" imgSRC="data/363_layer_0.png"/>
       <layer id="layer_3" imgSRC="data/364_layer_0.png"/>
 </prod>
```

what do i have to do?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) select the node that will be the parent of the new child, I'd go with `xpath`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assuming XML in $x
$node = $xml->xpath("//prod[@id='2']/layer[@id='layer_2']")[0];
```

`xpath` will select all `<layer>` nodes with `id=layer_2` that have `<prod>` with `id=2` as a parent. In case there are several results, the `[0]` will select just the first one. This works with `PHP >= 5.4`.

see this working: http://3v4l.org/5Q46F

(2) then add the child and its attributes, see `example #10` in the `simplexml` manual:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

Comment: @BảoTrần: Welcome, glad I could help. Please consider to accept the answer = click green tick on the left.